# unsupported buffer type when running migrations

Tags: rust, mysql-connector, rust-diesel, rust-diesel-mysql

So, my problem is that I cannot successfully run migrations in my Rust/Diesel backend web app using MySQL as the database on Windows 11.

I have tried two different MySQL lib/DLL file versions (8.3 and 8.0) and have reinstalled the Diesel CLI. I also installed the MySQL community server side by side with my XAMPP installation with MariaDB, neither one works, but the error message is the same.

Rust version: `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`

MySQL version: `8.0.36 (MySQL Community Server)` (EDIT: formerly 8.3.0)

The actual error message when running either `diesel setup` or `diesel migration run` is the following:

```
Using unsupported buffer type: 253  (parameter: 1)
```

My first migration file (`up.sql`) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
);
```

Here's my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "budget"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4.24", features = ["serde"] }
rocket = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["json"] }
diesel = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["mysql", "chrono"] }
diesel_migrations = "2.1.0"
dotenvy = "0.15"
rocket_db_pools = { version = "0.1.0", features = ["diesel_mysql"] }
```

I'm very new to Rust and would appreciate even if someone could point me in the right direction. I don't currently know where to start looking for the underlying problem. I can provide more information as needed.

Comment: Why are you using an alpha status (unstable) mysql version?

Comment: @Shadow It was the first one presented on the MySQL downloads page (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). I'll try to downgrade to a stable version

Comment: @Shadow I now installed MySQL 8.0.36, but the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

- I first installed MySQL 8.0.36 (Community Server)
- then I changed the `MYSQLCLIENT_LIB_DIR` environment variable in advanced system settings to point to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib`
- then I reinstalled `diesel_cli` with the `--no-default-features` and `--features "mysql"` flags

After that, running `diesel setup` and `diesel migration run/redo/revert` worked.